# JQuery - Slice/Remove - Special characters from ID or class name

Tags: jquery

For Japanese language, I am trying to get Japanese added dynamically from the backend.

I want to ignore the special characters, because I am getting "

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression:
```

Is it possible to remove `-(スーペリアルーム)` from `superior-room-(スーペリアルーム)` and get only `superior-room`?

I need the output to be id="superior-room".

**HTML:**

```
    <div id =superior-room-(スーペリアルーム)" class="list-item">
      <p>Title</p>
    </div>
```

**JS:**

```
    var message = '';
    var numAvailableRooms;
    var roomContianerId = $('.list-item').attr('id');

    if (numAvailableRooms < 100) {
      message = '50 rooms left!';
    } else {
      message = 'High demand!';
    }

    if (message == '') {
      $('#' + roomContianerId + ' .demand-message').hide();
    } else {
      $('#' + roomContianerId + ' .demand-message').show();
      $('#' + roomContianerId + ' .demand-message').html(message);
    }
```

Comment: Careful of: `id =superior-room-` you're missing an opening `"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `pop` and `split` you can get new id without (スーペリアルーム) and set new id to div like below.

```js
var  id = $('div').attr('id');
var arr = id.split("-");
//remove last element from array
var popItem = arr.pop();
//change array back to string and replace , with -
var result = arr.toString().replace(',','-');
//Give New ID for div
$('div').attr('id',result)
console.log($('div').attr('id'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id =superior-room-(スーペリアルーム)" class="list-item">
  <p>Title</p>
</div>
```

Comment: WOW! You made my day. I've been stuck with a similar pb for weeks. I've tried Regex solutions with no satisfactory results. And I didn't know about pop() and shift() methods.
BIG THANKS

Answer (score 3):

Using jQuery you can update only after page load, to update you can use [`attr()`](https://api.jquery.com/attr/) method. First of all, get all elements with an id attribute(use [has attribute selector](https://api.jquery.com/has-attribute-selector/)) and use [`attr()`](https://api.jquery.com/attr/) method with the callback to iterate and update id.

```
$('[id]').attr('id', function(i, id){
    // replace all character except word char, digit and -
    // using negated character class in regex
    return id.replace(/[^\w\d-]/g, '');
});
```

---

To make it fully valid refer : [Javascript regex to remove illegal characters from DOM ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9635625/javascript-regex-to-remove-illegal-characters-from-dom-id).

```
$('[id]').attr('id', function(i, id){
    return id.replace(/^[^a-z]+|[^\w:.-]+/gi, "");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascripts splice to split at last occurrence of the hypen (-).

```js
var str = "superior-room-(スーペリアルーム)";
var idx = "superior-room-(スーペリアルーム)".lastIndexOf('-');
console.log(str.split('').splice(0,13).join(''));
```

Hope this helps.